# Compute method is failing to assign values - Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I' am trying to assign values when a users belongs into a project in this case the project name and manager to which he is assigned but the compute method gives an error, I've tried to log in the values just in case one of them came empty but no they definitely have the required data.
we can see in the logs:
root: Staff Augmentation - project_task.project_id.display_name
root: 120 - project_task.project_id.delivery_director.id

```
@api.depends('user_id')
    @api.model
    def _get_assigned_project(self):
        today = fields.Date.today()
        for employee in self:
            project_task = self.env['project.task'].search([('user_id','=',employee.user_id.id),
                                                                ('status','=','assigned'),
                                                                ('date_end','>',today),
                                                                ('project_id.original_project_id', '=', False)], order='date_end desc', limit=1)
            if project_task:
                employee.project_name = project_task.project_id.display_name
                if project_task.project_id.role_id.name = 'Delivery Manager' and employee.base_manager != 0:
                    employee.parent_id = project_task.project_id.delivery_director.id
                else:
                    employee.parent_id = project_task.project_id.delivery_manager.id
            else: 
                employee.project_name = ""
                if employee.base_manager != 0:
                    employee.parent_id = employee.base_manager
```

this is the error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Compute method failed to assign hr.employee(266,).project_name
```

Comment: should employee have a tuple? sometimes this is the result of a sneaky trailing comma

Comment: No the employee should't have a tuple just one value

Comment: the fields im using in this function are: project_name = fields.Char('project.project', compute='_get_assigned_project') & base_manager = fields.Integer('Base Manager')

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign employee.parent_id in your compute method , If your if else are failed to assign the value to the field than this error will comes up.

So check your method and put an else condition after your if condition and give assignment like employee.parent_id = False.
Because if in any case your compute method failed to assign value which we think it should be, than they throws  error.

Answer (score 1):

Put default value for the field to be assigned in case it did'n fulfill the computed assignment condition